# Phaser: Make background screen-width instead of content-width

Tags: android, phaser-framework

I am making a game using the Phaser Framework for Android.  I need to make the canvas fill the entire screen width and then flood it with background color, then put content in the center of screen.  Currently, even though I already set the width of the canvas to window width, Phaser still reset it to content width, which is smaller, then filling only the content width with background.

How do I stop Phaser from using content width?

```
var gameObj = new Phaser.Game($(".parent").width(), 700, Phaser.CANVAS, 'parent');

gameObj.stage.backgroundColor = '#A6E5F5';
gameObj.load.image('prld', 'prl.png');

gameObj.scale.scaleMode = Phaser.ScaleManager.SHOW_ALL;
gameObj.scale.pageAlignHorizontally = true;
gameObj.scale.pageAlignVertically = true;
gameObj.scale.setScreenSize(true);
gameObj.scale.refresh();

gameObj.stage.backgroundColor = '#A6E5F5';    

// Load Content Here
gameObj.load.image('h1', 'res1/h1.png');
gameObj.load.image('h2', 'res1/h2.png');
....
g = gameObj.add.group();
g.create(20, 20, 'h1');
g.create(60, 20, 'h2');
....
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i use this code in my game and it work very nice without changing in position of any elements

```
var targetWidth = 720; // the width of the game we want
var targetHeight = 480; // the height of the game we want

// additional ratios

//Small – 360x240
//Normal – 480x320
//Large – 720x480
//XLarge – 960x640
//XXLarge – 1440x960

var deviceRatio = (window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight); //device aspect ratio

var newRatio = (targetHeight/targetWidth)*deviceRatio; //new ratio to fit the screen

var newWidth = targetWidth*newRatio;
var newHeight = targetHeight;

var gameWidth = newWidth;
var gameHeight = newHeight;
var gameRendrer = Phaser.AUTO;
```

and this code for Boot state

```
game.scale.scaleMode = Phaser.ScaleManager.SHOW_ALL;

        game.scale.pageAlignHorizontally = true;
        game.scale.pageAlignVertically = true;
        game.scale.forceLandscape = true;
        game.scale.setScreenSize(true);
```

this for landscape mode if you want to make it for portrait change width and height like

```
var targetWidth = 480; // the width of the game we want
var targetHeight = 720; // the height of the game we want
```

also force it to portrait

this code work well in my games 
[image: phaser screen shots]

[image]

Comment: I dont see the function setSreenSize function in the phaser dist https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser/blob/v2.4.4/src/core/ScaleManager.js. can you tell me which version you are using? also, what will be the equivalent function for the new phaser version?

Answer (score 8):

You need Phaser 2.2+ for this, but if you want the canvas to fill the entire screen space available you would do:

```
var game = new Phaser.Game("100%", "100%", Phaser.CANVAS, 'parent');

...

game.scale.scaleMode = Phaser.ScaleManager.RESIZE;
```

Also you should not use pageAlign if you're using 100% dimensions. You also don't need to call refresh or setScreenSize.

When working in the RESIZE scale mode you can add a function to your States called 'resize'. It will be called whenever the screen dimensions change (orientation event perhaps) and be passed 2 parameters: width and  height. Use those to adjust your game content layout.

You may want to get the [Phaser Scale Manager book](https://leanpub.com/phaserscalemanager), it covers all this in lots more detail (caveat: I wrote it, but it has a "pay what you want" price, including completely free)

Comment: Any example to scale bipmapdata, tilemaps, etc in RESIZE scale mode? We need more examples about this :)