# Maximum Image/SpriteSheet Dimension for mobile phaser.js

Tags: javascript, image, optimization, phaser-framework

I'm a newbee on this area.

I am currently developing card games. just for fun

on desktop i don't encounter problems on drawing portion of image on a sprite sheet to the canvas using Phaser-framework.

But when i move my application to open it on mobile browsers
like the Phaser cannot draw portion of the sprite sheet to the canvas because of the image being used is 1012 x 3324 in dimension;

Does anyone has any idea on what it the maximum sprite sheet for mobile browsers

im not having on trouble on chrome browser.

but when used firefox and android browser give me trouble.

[ctx.drawImage gives NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE](https://www.google.com.ph/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDYQFjAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fforums.udacity.com%2Fquestions%2F100146950%2Fctxdrawimage-gives-ns_error_not_available&ei=R2k0Ve73AqPAmAWj64GYBQ&usg=AFQjCNEkYmMKvn_L7qVoGDQ0WZuTcm7sfw&sig2=tzv0OgKxTJabwEnKP6dl3A&bvm=bv.91071109,d.dGY)

[Bug 574330 - NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE with canvas.drawImage and Image.onload](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=574330)

hope you could help me out.

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to scale canvas to fit on any screen check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28227090/phaser-make-background-screen-width-instead-of-content-width/28278332#28278332) it might help

Comment: Already do that. But the scale image is not drawn to the canvas. Give error ns_available_error