# How to create adaptive games via Phaser

Tags: javascript, jquery, phaser-framework, adaptive-design

I'm creating a simple game via Phaser.io
How do I make it display properly on different screens?

When I use this:

```
var w = window.innerWidth * window.devicePixelRatio,
h = window.innerHeight * window.devicePixelRatio;

var avaProfile = game.add.image(w/1.66, h/6.3, 'avaProfile');
avaProfile.fixedToCamera = true;
```

something like this happens:

[image]

And I can't even imagine how can I make all elements be adaptive

Comment: Have you read this article? Can help for mobile adaptation. http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2015/04/23/how-to-lock-orientation-in-your-html5-responsive-game-using-phaser/

Comment: take look at this answer 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28227090/phaser-make-background-screen-width-instead-of-content-width/28278332#28278332

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, if you want to position your button according to the game size, you should probably use game.width/game.height which are more reliable.

Now if you want to adapt your button's position according to the screen size, there's no magic solution. Here's a generic article about the topic for instance. You should decide from which origin you'll position each UI element, be it a screen corner, the center of the screen, a gameplay object, etc. and anticipate how things will turn out if the resolution changes.

For example, if you want to have a square pop-up in the center of your screen, you'll do something like:

```
var popup = game.add.sprite(game.width/2, game.height/2, 'popup');
popup.width = 400;
popup.height = 400;
popup.anchor.set(0.5, 0.5);
```

Now to give it a title, you'll probably want to position it according to the popup itself:

```
 var text = game.add.sprite(popup.x, popup.y + 10, 'Hello world');
 text.anchor.set(0.5, 0);
```

etc. There's no one-solution-fits-all but make it clear what uses what as the origin and hopefully you won't have surprises when resizing the screen.