# Disable auto-resizing in Phaser 2

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, phaser-framework

I'm creating a responsive game with Phaser 2. The width is fixed to 360 and the height gets calculated to a fitting ratio.

```
var height = (360 * screen.height) / screen.width;
var game = new Phaser.Game(360, ratio, Phaser.AUTO, "", {preload: preload, create: create, update: update});
```

In the create() function I then resize it to 100%, so the screen is filled:

```
function create () {
   document.querySelector("canvas").style.width = "100%";
   document.querySelector("canvas").style.height = "100%";
   // more stuff...
}
```

However, if I now click or do anything, the canvas gets resized back to 360xheight. How can I disable that?

Thanks

Comment: this answer might help 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28227090/phaser-make-background-screen-width-instead-of-content-width/28278332#28278332

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Phaser actually has the ability to scale the game/canvas to the width or height of the window built-in.

Try using the [ScaleManager](http://phaser.io/docs/2.4.7/Phaser.ScaleManager.html#scaleMode) instead. In your case probably `SHOW_ALL`, and it can be set in your boot state (meaning early on in your code):

```
this.scale.scaleMode = Phaser.ScaleManager.SHOW_ALL;
```

You can see an example of this in practice in [this tutorial on State](http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2014/08/28/phaser-tutorial-understanding-phaser-states/), and [the official example](http://phaser.io/examples/v2/input/game-scale).

Comment: This answer relates to Phaser 2 and it out-dated. Phaser.ScaleManager.SHOW_ALL doesn't exist.

Comment: This question was asked and answered before Phaser 3 was released. :) I'll edit the question title accordingly.