# overall loss of quality - Phaser

Tags: javascript, html, phaser-framework, software-quality

I'm developing an interactive with Phaser.js (v2) but I'm facing an overall loss of quality (images, sprites, texts, etc). Especially rendering text:

```
const strtxt = this.game.add.text(0, 0, str, {
  font: 'Open Sans',
  fontSize: 17,
  weight: 400,
}, text);
strtxt.align = 'center';
strtxt.lineSpacing = -4;
strtxt.anchor.set(0.5, 0);
strtxt.wordWrap = true;
strtxt.wordWrapWidth = 300;
const y = text.getAt(1).height + ((index + 1) * 60);
strtxt.position.set(250, y);
```

[image]

I would really like to improve the quality, at least for the text.
What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Phaser will typically render to a fixed canvas and then stretch that canvas to fill the screen. For example if you set the canvas size to 480 x 640 pixels but play it on a HD monitor, then it's "blown up" so to speak. It's a lower resolution image shown in a higher-resolution display and that is why it looks slightly blurry.

The advantage is that the game will always display the same size. You as programmer don't have to worry about the many different display resolutions and sizes, especially with tablet or mobile phones. But the downside is loss of resolution and blurriness.

So I guess you want a pixel-to-pixel ratio, not sure if Phaser supports this but I think you can set `scaleMode` to `SHOW_ALL`, or perhaps `USER_SCALE` and then add custom functions to handle the resize events. Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36811929/disable-auto-resizing-in-phaser) or [this forum topic](http://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/31404-scaling-to-fill-screen-maintain-pixel-ratio-but-not-aspect-ratio/)